# Deployment error: You are not allowed to modify record types on Idea

Tags: deployment, record-type, ideas

I've got an errors during deployment an existing project which has been developed in dev. org to a fresh dev. org:

> 1. (Idea.InternalIdeasIdeaRecordType) -- Error: You are not allowed to modify record types on Idea (line 50, column 18)
> 2. objects/Idea.object (Idea.Record_type_for_community_09a90000000TZewAAG_entity_Idea) -- Error: You are not allowed to modify record types on Idea (line 71, column 18)
> 3. objects/Question.object (Question.Record_type_for_community_09a90000000TZewAAG_entity_Question) -- Error: You are not allowed to modify record types on Question (line 31, column 18)
> 4. objects/Question.object (Question.Record_type_for_community_09a90000000hbn7AAA_entity_Question) -- Error: You are not allowed to modify record types on Question (line 79, column 18)

I tried to deploy via Ant Migration tool as well as via Eclipse and got the same results in either case.

Idea object structure:
[image]

**Please point me in the right direction**

Comment: I notice that a Community is referenced numerous times above. Does your existing Dev Org have one? What about the new Dev Org? Is a Community required for your project to work? If so, you may need to create the Community first in the new Dev Org.

Comment: @crmprogdev I' trying to deploy to the new org, deployment to existing org is OK. Community is exactly required and it was created before deployment. Also I see an Id-depending on name of record types and I changed it to relevant Ids. Only one way how I can to deploy is removing both record types from a metadata.

Comment: This is *not* my area of expertise, was just making the observation & asked the question. You mention Record Type name. Did you mean developer name? If not, may want to try that instead. Otherwise, have no additional suggestions for you.

Comment: any update on this?Getting the same errors :(